# Change date into fiscal month pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to change the date in my df into a fiscal month in a new column using python pandas.

This is an example

```
17/01/2016    201601
18/01/2016    201602
```

Could you help me to get the required python code?

Comment: could you please define what is `fiscal month`?

Comment: as you can see in the example the fiscal month is from the 18th of the month till the 17th of the next month. So if the date is the 18th than it must show the YYYY-MM + 1 month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
In [29]: df['fiscal_month'] = np.where(df.Date.dt.day < 18, df.Date, df.Date + pd.DateOffset(months=1))

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
        Date        new fiscal_month
0 2016-01-17 2016-01-17   2016-01-17
1 2016-01-18 2016-02-01   2016-02-18

In [31]: df.fiscal_month = df.fiscal_month.dt.strftime('%Y%m')

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
        Date        new fiscal_month
0 2016-01-17 2016-01-17       201601
1 2016-01-18 2016-02-01       201602
```